# Polymer multiple similar elements and click events

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to build a custom polymer element which has a div like this

```
<core-menu>
    <paper-item on-tap={{openPage}}><core-icon icon="add"></core-icon> Add Issues</paper-item>
    <paper-item on-tap={{openPage}}><core-icon icon="view-list"></core-icon> View Issues</paper-item>
    <paper-item on-tap={{openPage}}><core-icon icon="lock"></core-icon>Logout</paper-item>
</core-menu>
```

And this `openPage` function needs to provide this kind of operation

```
 openPage: function(event, details, sender) {
        console.log("open page called item "+ item);
 }
```

I am not sure how to get the item clicked. Say, if I click on the Logout item, i would like the value of item to be a number, like something that could say that nth paper-item was clicked.

I dont know how to get this value from `event` or `details` or `sender`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<core-menu>
   <paper-item data-action-id="1" on-tap={{openPage}}><core-icon icon="add"></core-icon> Add Issues</paper-item>
   <paper-item data-action-id="2" on-tap={{openPage}}><core-icon icon="view-list"></core-icon> View Issues</paper-item>
   <paper-item data-action-id="3" on-tap={{openPage}}><core-icon icon="lock"></core-icon>Logout</paper-item>
</core-menu>
```

And then:

```
openPage: function(event, details, sender) {
    console.log("open page called item "+ sender.target.attributes["data-action-id"]);
}
```

"sender.target" is returning paper-item